# Cómo puedo sacar por pantalla todo el objeto después de hacer un `stream()`?

Tags: java

Tengo un código con el cual filtro una lista para que todos los objetos con peso menor de 40kg se le incremente 10kg.

Esto consigo hacerlo bien en el `stream()` pero justo después me gustaría poder sacar por pantalla de nuevo todo el objeto que cumpla con esta condición y no solo el atributo.

Adjunto el trozo de código que me hace esto:

```
people.stream()
    .mapToDouble(Person->Person.getWeight()+10)
    .filter(Person->Person<40)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Justo quiero que cuando imprima no solo sea el `getWeight()` sino todo el objeto.

Muchísimas gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es eliminar el `mapToDouble()` y filtrar directamente por el atributo que deseas dentro del objeto. Luego le agregas a cada objeto el peso que quieras.

```
people.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getWeight() < 40)// o la condición que quieras
    .map(person -> {
            // Agrego 10 al peso actual que ya se que es menor que 40 kg
            person.setWeight(person.getWeight() + 10);
            // Devuelvo el mismo objeto modificado
            return person;
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);// Imprimo todo el objeto
```

***NOTA:*** Es importante recordar que para que imprima todos los valores de los atributos del objeto debes sobrescribir el método `toString()` en la clase de dicho objeto.